# /build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2) flutter error

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I fix this error?

Everything worked completely fine, disconnected my external hard-drive, and a day later my projects doesn't work anymore....

(The project is located on my external hard drive, drive has no issues by itself tho)

```
niekbiesterbos@mbp-van-niek schoolEachother0_1 % flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
 
Running Xcode build...                                                  
                                                   
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                        27,4s
Xcode build done.                                           45,0s
FileSystemException: Deletion failed, path = '/Volumes/Nieks
drive/Development/apps/schoolEachother0_1/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app'
(OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough information to give you a definitive answer, but try this:

1. Plug your hard drive in to your pc
2. Navigate to the `Runner.app` file
3. Copy the path and paste it somewhere handy
4. Compare the actual path to the path in the error.

From the error, I can only assume that there is a path messed up/missing somewhere. Comparing the actual path to the path in the error may shine some light on the issue

It also may be worth trying `flutter clean`

Comment: 2022-11-23 17:00:58.844996+0200 Runner[1531:288186] fopen failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory) I have this error, can you help me with the solution I didn't understand your answer where can I change the path

Answer (score 0):

I changed the directory of the project to the root directory which Mac OS is installed and it worked.